# User Input from API - Gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following scenario in gitlab .

1. The first get API call returns the list of transport ids and it description.
2. From the list derived in Step 1 , I need to ask the user to choose or type in a transport id.
3. Based on the user input from Step 2, I call another API to import the object.

Can the gitlab allows a user input dynamically in the pipeline or can it brings up a popup to ask for the user input during the merge request trigger?

Comment: You can create a custom script that interacts with the user and takes input. This script can then be invoked as part of your pipeline job. While this approach doesn't provide a popup within the GitLab UI, it can still achieve user interaction within the pipeline. You can use the script section in your .gitlab-ci.yml to execute the script.

Comment: @syam - Do you have a sample or link where i can use this? I tried searching but could not find the relavant example

Comment: I don't think this will work as the shell session running the contents of the script is not in interactive mode